# Logic behind assigning an NSData object to another NSData object

Tags: objective-c

I inherited an app written in Objective C.  It is an app that writes to an external Sandisk iXpand usb drive using SDK provided by Sandisk.

Occasionally, I see the app crash where it appears that a process was terminated because it dereferenced a NULL pointer.

Which leads me to my question about the logic being used when the NSData object "*_writeData" is set to be equal to another NSData object "srcData".  I am wondering if srcData is NULL for some reason on occasion and that is causing the crash.

So, can someone explain if it is a logical thing to do this line?  It seems redundant to me:

`NSData *_writedata = srcData`

Why not just use srcData directly like this:

`dataCount = [[iXpandFileSystemController sharedController] writeFile:createResult writeBuf:srcData writeSize:(uint32_t)trans];`

And if it a logical thing to do `NSData *_writedata = srcData`, is there a way to protect or catch when it points to a NULL pointer.

This is the code block I am referring to:

```
int total = 0;
    int startByte = 0;
    int  singleTransfer = 8 * 1024 * 1024;
    long createResult = 0;

    [[iXpandFileSystemController sharedController]  deleteFileAbsolutePath:dstPath];
    createResult = [[iXpandFileSystemController sharedController] openFileAbsolutePath:dstPath openMode:OF_CREATE | OF_WRITE];

    NSError* error;
    NSFileHandle* fileHandler = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingFromURL:videoURL error:&error];

    uint32_t dataCount = 0;
    NSTimeInterval startTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

    while(true){
        @synchronized(self) {
        @autoreleasepool {

        NSData* srcData = [fileHandler readDataOfLength:singleTransfer];
        if([srcData length] == 0){
            break;
        }

        int len = (int)[srcData length];

        int trans = len;
        NSData *_writeData = srcData;

        dataCount = [[iXpandFileSystemController sharedController] writeFile:createResult writeBuf:_writeData writeSize:(uint32_t)trans];
        NSLog(@"writing data  %ld bytes", dataCount);

        if (dataCount == -1)
        {
            [self.consoleString  appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@] [Failed  ] ------ Failed \n", [self convertDateFormat:[NSDate date]]]];

            return NO;
        }
        total += trans;

        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nah-- you're thinking too much about this one.  It doesn't make any sense.   No threads involved so `_writeData` is just a copy of the pointer in `srcData`.

Comment: @bbum  Thanks.  I'm too embarrassed to admit just how much I have been overthinking it!  :)  Thanks for responding and info.  I appreciate it!

Comment: No worries!   Having been handed many a very large codebase of very broken code, it is quite easy to start second guessing even the most basic realities of code flow when faced with such a pile of "how in the heck did this EVER work?!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And if it a logical thing to do `NSData *_writedata = srcData`, is there a way to protect or catch when it points to a `NULL` pointer.

In your code when the above assignment is executed `srcData` is known to be non-null due to the preceding:

```
if([srcData length] == 0){
   break;
}
```

The expression `[srcData length]` will evaluate to zero if `srcData` is null or if it's non-null and `length` returns zero. So once past this `srcData` is known to be non-null.

You are correct, the assignments to both `_writeData` and `trans` are redundant but harmless.

Whatever your issue is it isn't these assignments.

Good hunting!

Comment: Thank you for the information and clear explanation!